# jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: object has no attribute

Tags: python, flask, shelve

I am trying to create an Inventory Management System in which i can create/add stock through a form(WTForms) and have it displayed in a table on a separate page. Currently, i am stuck on the stated error. I have looked everywhere for an answer to no avail. I am supposed to add stock through 'createGPU.html' and be directed to 'retrieveGPU.html'

Clicking the submit button in createGPU results in jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'GPUs.GPUs object' has no attribute 'GPUName'

Main Program

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from Forms import CreateGPUForm
import shelve, GPUs

@app.route("/createGPU", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createGPU():
    createGPUForm = CreateGPUForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and createGPUForm.validate():
        gpuDict = {}
        db = shelve.open('storage.db', 'c')

        try:
            gpuDict = db['GPU']
        except:
            print('Error in retrieving GPUs from storage.db.')

        gpu = GPUs.GPUs(createGPUForm.GPUName.data, createGPUForm.GPUUnitPrice.data, createGPUForm.GPUStock.data,createGPUForm.GPUSales.data)
        gpuDict[gpu.get_GPUNo()] = gpu
        db['GPU'] = gpuDict
        db.close()

        return redirect(url_for('retrieveGPU'))
    return render_template('createGPU.html', form=createGPUForm)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

@app.route('/retrieveGPU')
def retrieveGPU():
    gpuDict = {}
    db = shelve.open('storage.db', 'r')
    gpuDict = db['GPU']
    db.close()

    gpuList = []
    for key in gpuDict:
        gpu = gpuDict.get(key)
        gpuList.append(gpu)

    return render_template('retrieveGPU.html',gpuList=gpuList, count=len(gpuList))
```

createGPU

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}GPU-Assist - Add Graphics Card{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% from "includes/_formhelper.html" import render_field %}

<h1 class="display-4">Add Graphics Card</h1>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.GPUName, class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.GPUStock, class="form-control") }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.GPUUnitPrice, class="form-control")  }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ render_field(form.GPUSales, class="form-control")  }}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
  </form>



{% endblock %}
```

retrieveGPU

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}GPU-Assist - View GPU-Cart{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="display-4">View GPU</h1>
<div>
  {% if count == 0 %}
  <p>No GPU in recorded in inventory.</p>
  {% elif count == 1 %}
  <p>There is 1 GPU recorded in the inventory.</p>
  {% else %}
  <p>There are {{ count }} GPUs recorded in the inventory.</p>
  {% endif %}
</div> <!--End of display number of users div-->

<div>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Sales</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {% for gpu in gpuList %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ gpu.GPUName() }}</td>
        <td>{{ gpu.GPUStock() }}</td>
        <td>{{ gpu.GPUUnitPrice() }}</td>
        <td>{{ gpu.GPUSales() }}</td>
        <td><a href="/updateGPU/{{gpu.get_GPUNo()}}" class="btn btn-warning">Update</a></td>
        <td>
          <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

GPUs.py

```
class GPUs:
    countID = 0
    def __init__(self,GPUName,GPUStock,GPUUnitPrice,GPUSales):
        GPUs.countID += 1
        self.__GPUName = GPUName
        self.__GPUStock = GPUStock
        self.__GPUUnitPrice = GPUUnitPrice
        self.__GPUSales = GPUSales
        self.__GPUNo=GPUs.countID


    '''
    One obvious limitation it has is that every time you restart the web application, the countID resets to 0. 
    Once the countID resets, the next newly created Users’s userID will start from 1 again and overwrite any User 
    that previously had __userID = 1.  (Must figure out an alternative)
    '''
    #Getter or Accessor
    def get_GPUNo(self):
        return self.__GPUNo
    def get_GPUName(self):
        return self.__GPUName
    def get_GPUStock(self):
        return self.__GPUStock
    def get_GPUUnitPrice(self):
        return self.__GPUUnitPrice
    def get_GPUSales(self):
        return self.__GPUSales

    #Settor or Mutator
    def set_GPUNo(self, GPUNo):
        self.__GPUNo = GPUNo
    def set_GPUName(self, GPUName):
        self.__GPUName = GPUName
    def set_GPUStock(self, GPUStock):
        self.__GPUStock = GPUStock
    def set_GPUUnitPrice(self, GPUUnitPrice):
        self.__GPUUnitPrice = GPUUnitPrice
    def set_GPUSales(self, GPUSales):
        self.__GPUSales = GPUSales
```

Answer (score 3):

When Jinja2 processes

```
    <td>{{ gpu.GPUName() }}</td>
```

it expects that `gpu` will have a callable member function named `GPUName`. The way you've coded things up, `get_GPUName` is what you want instead.

The Pythonic way would be to drop the getters and setters entirely, removed the double-underscore prefixes, and have the template go directly for the named instance variable.

```
    <td>{{ gpu.GPUName }}</td>
```